# Compute the mean of two columns in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, semantics

I have a dataframe storing different values. Sample:

```
a$open  a$high  a$low   a$close

1.08648 1.08707 1.08476 1.08551
1.08552 1.08623 1.08426 1.08542
1.08542 1.08572 1.08453 1.08465
1.08468 1.08566 1.08402 1.08554
1.08552 1.08565 1.08436 1.08464
1.08463 1.08543 1.08452 1.08475
1.08475 1.08504 1.08427 1.08436
1.08433 1.08438 1.08275 1.08285
1.08275 1.08353 1.08275 1.08325
1.08325 1.08431 1.08315 1.08378
1.08379 1.08383 1.08275 1.08294
1.08292 1.08338 1.08271 1.08325
```

What I want to do, is creating a new column `a$mean` storing the mean of `a$high` and `a$low` for each row.

Here is how I achieved that:

```
highlowmean <- function(highs, lows){
  m <- vector(mode="numeric", length=0)
  for (i in 1:length(highs)){
    m[i] <- mean(highs[i], lows[i])
  }
  return(m)
}

a$mean <- highlowmean(a$high, a$low)
```

However I'm a bit new into R and in functionnal languages in general, so I'm pretty sure that there is a more efficient/simple way to achieve that.

How to achieve that the smartest way?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

We can use `rowMeans`

```
 a$mean <- rowMeans(a[,c('high', 'low')], na.rm=TRUE)
```

NOTE: If there are NA values, it is better to use `rowMeans`

For example

```
 a <- data.frame(High= c(NA, 3, 2), low= c(3, NA, 0))
 rowMeans(a, na.rm=TRUE)    
 #[1] 3 3 1
```

and using `+`

```
 a1 <- replace(a, is.na(a), 0)
 (a1[1] + a1[2])/2
#  High
#1  1.5
#2  1.5
#3  1.0
```

NOTE: This is no way trying to tarnish the other answer.  It works in most cases and is fast as well.

Comment: What would be the behavior to not using rowMeans? NA will be taken as 0?

Comment: @LoveMetal  Just check this `mean(c(3, NA), na.rm=TRUE)` and `(3+0)/2`

Answer (score 11):

For the mean of two numbers you don't really need any special functions:

```
a$mean = (a$high + a$low) / 2
```

For such an easy case, this avoids any conversions to `matrix` to use `apply` or `rowMeans`.