# avg of 2 columns and make an another column for the resultant average.I want to do these operations in R programming

Tags: r, average

```
med<-function(starts,ends)
{
m<-vector(mode="numeric",length=0)
for(i in 1:length(starts)) 
{
m[i]<-((starts[i]+ends[i])/2)
}
 return (m)
}

fimopositive$V6<-med(fimopositive$V2,fimopositive$V3)
```

here fimopositive is the data frame having four columns V1,V2,V3,V4.I want the avg of V2 and V3 and result should be stored in a new column V5 .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compute the mean of two columns in a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33981527/compute-the-mean-of-two-columns-in-a-dataframe)

Answer (score 0):

```
fimopositive["V5"] <- rowMeans(fimopositive[c("V2", "V3")])
```