# How to find geometric mean of any 2 columns in a dataframe in r and store it in a new column?

Tags: r, list, dataframe

```
gm={}
for (r in 1:nrow(dat1)){
  x={}
  for (m in 1:ncol(dat1)){
    for (n in m+1:ncol(dat1)){
      x[r]=x[r]+sqrt(dat1[r,m]*dat1[r,n])
      gm[[r]]=x[r]
      r=r+1
      
    }
  }
}
```

here dat1 is my dataframe. I am creating an empty list and trying to append it, but it gives me null result.

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(dat1)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(dat1, 20))`.

Answer (score 2):

The function below finds all pairwise combinations of columns of a data.frame and computes their geometric mean.

```
geomMean <- function(x, m = 2){
  gmean <- function(x, na.rm = FALSE) {
    prod(x, na.rm = na.rm)^(1/length(x))
  }
  #
  inx <- seq_len(ncol(x))
  y <- combn(inx, m, function(i){
    apply(x[, i], 1, gmean)
  })
  dimnames(y) <- list(rownames(x),
                      combn(names(x), m, paste, collapse = "_"))
  
  as.data.frame(y)
}

geomMean(mtcars)
```

---

With the data in [Allan Cameron's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64193993/8245406) the results are the same though the output has a different form.

```
geomMean(dat1)
#   col1_col2
#1   2.000000
#2   2.000000
#3   6.928203
#4   5.000000
#5   4.242641
#6   8.366600
#7   1.732051
#8   8.485281
#9   5.291503
#10  9.486833
```

Answer (score 1):

You're making this much harder than it needs to be because you are ignoring the fact that mathematical operations in R are vectorized.

Suppose I have a data frame like this:

```r
set.seed(69)
dat1 <- data.frame(col1 = sample(10), col2 = sample(10))

dat1
#>    col1 col2
#> 1     1    4
#> 2     2    2
#> 3     8    6
#> 4     5    5
#> 5     6    3
#> 6     7   10
#> 7     3    1
#> 8     9    8
#> 9     4    7
#> 10   10    9
```

Then I can add a new column containing the geometric mean of any two named columns like this:

```r
dat1$col3 <- sqrt(dat1[,"col1"] * dat1[,"col2"])
```

So `dat1` now looks like this:

```r
dat1
#>    col1 col2     col3
#> 1     1    4 2.000000
#> 2     2    2 2.000000
#> 3     8    6 6.928203
#> 4     5    5 5.000000
#> 5     6    3 4.242641
#> 6     7   10 8.366600
#> 7     3    1 1.732051
#> 8     9    8 8.485281
#> 9     4    7 5.291503
#> 10   10    9 9.486833
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it.

```
geomean <- function(col1, col2){
  m <- vector(mode="numeric", length=0)
  for (i in 1:length(col1)){
    m[i] <- sqrt(col1[i]*col2[i])
  }
  return(m)
}

a$mean <- geomean(col1, col2)
```

Source: [https://www.antoinechampion.com/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33981527/compute-the-mean-of-two-columns-in-a-dataframe)